# Spring Mail - sending email in separate thread can't find the attachments temp files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, jakarta-mail

When trying to send an email with attachments in new thread I get java.io.FileNotFoundException

The feature is a part of Java 8, Spring boot 2.1.5 application with embedded Tomcat.
I get some input data from frontend form, sometimes with attachments. At some point in the business logic an email is sent with form data and the attachments if there were any.

I wanted to send the email in non blocking way so I run preparing and sending email method in new thread but then the JavaMailSender.send() method cannot find the attached files.
The files received from frontend form by REST Api are saved by Tomcat as temp files in temp folder and are probably deleted before email is sent.

The email itself is MimeMessage with Multipart containing, the email text and one to three attachments, not exceeding 10 MB size.

**Main logic with sending mial in new thread:**

```java
public FormConfirmation productReturn(FormDataInput formData, List<MultipartFile> attachments) {

        try {
            FormConfirmation formConfirmation = formSendingService.prepareAndSendFormData(formData);
            return complaintConfirmation;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            new Thread(() -> notificationSendingService.notifyAboutUnhandledForm(formData, attachments)).start();
            throw new ErrorSendingFormException(e);
        }

    }
```

**Root casue exception:**

```java
Caused by: org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\pawelk\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.2114838244298062234.8080\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\upload_1e03fce2_e99b_459c_87b0_b79bbe9eb7ca_00000001.tmp (The system cannot find the file specified);
```

**Mail sending method**:

```java
public void notifyAboutUnhandledForm(FormDataInput formData, List<MultipartFile> attachments) {
        try {
            MimeMessage message = emailPreparer.prepareNotificationEmail(formData, attachments);
            emailSender.send(message);
        } catch (MessagingException | MailException | IOException ex) {
            logger.error(EMAIL_SENDING_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE + ex);
            throw new ErrorSendingFormException(EMAIL_SENDING_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE, ex);
        }
    }
```

**Full email preparing class:**

```java
@Service
public class EmailMessagePreparer {

    public static final String EMAIL_TITLE = "Email title";
    @Value("${spring.mail.username}")
    private String senderAddress;
    @Value("#{'${email.notification.recipients}'.split(',')}")
    private String[] emailRecipients;
    @Inject
    private EmailTemplateProvider templateProvider;
    @Inject
    private JavaMailSender emailSender;

    MimeMessage prepareNotificationEmail(FormDataInput formData, List<MultipartFile> attachments) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();

        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
        helper.setTo(emailRecipients);
        helper.setSubject(EMAIL_TITLE);
        helper.setFrom(senderAddress);
        helper.setText(templateProvider.provideEmailContentFromHTMLTemplate(formData), true);

        for (MultipartFile multipart : attachments) {
            addAttachmentToTheEmailMessage(helper, multipart);
        }
        return message;
    }

    private void addAttachmentToTheEmailMessage(MimeMessageHelper helper, MultipartFile multipart) throws IOException, MessagingException {
        helper.addAttachment(multipart.getOriginalFilename(), multipart);
    }

    private String extractAndWriteFileExtension(MultipartFile multipart) {
        return multipart.getOriginalFilename().substring(multipart.getOriginalFilename().lastIndexOf("."));
    }

}
```

When I send the email in the same main thread the temp file are always available and execution is correct.
I expect that running the mail sending method in separate thread should have the same access to temp files which will not be deleted until they are in use by the program.

When sending the email without attachments or with attachments in single main thread all works fine.

Anyone have an idea what can cause the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Your thought process may be right. I would copy the temp attachment file to another directory, start your second process that sends the mail and delete the temp attachment file after the mail was succesfully send.

Comment: I've tried to create new separate tempFiles from those MultipartFiles and add them to the email int the EmallMessagePreparer class (running in new thread already) but that did not solve the problem. Even when I didn't remove them manually by File.delete(); at ale they disappeared from Tomcat temp folder before JavaMailSender sent the email.
Code in this version still worked when there was only one main thread.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if still needed but I found a solution:

The problem is that the stream of the multipartFile is getting closed by the initial thread, hence the moment the email is been sent asynchronously the stream is already closed. A quick solution would be to convert the multipartfile to a byte array (`multipartfile.getBytes()`), and pass that to your async call instead of passing the MultipartFile, then you can simply attach it to your helper:

```
helper.addAttachment(name, new ByteArrayResource(byte_array))
```